# How Can I Store a File Handle in a Perl Object and how can I access the result?

Tags: perl, object, file-io, methods, perl-data-structures

I wanted to store a file handle in a Perl Object.  Here is how I went about it.

```
sub openFiles {
     my $self = shift;
     open (my $itemsFile, "<", "items.txt")     or die $!;
     open (my $nameFile,  "<", "FullNames.txt") or die $!;      
     $self->{itemsFile} = $itemsFile;                   
     $self->{nameFile}  = $nameFile;
     return $self;
}
```

Then I'm looking to access some information from one of these files.  Here is how I go about it.

```
sub getItemDescription {
     my $self = @_;
     chomp(my $record = $self->{itemsFile});
     return $record;
}
```

I attempt to access it in another procedure as follows:

```
print "Test 3: $self->getItemDescription()\n";
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Is the way I'm saving the file handle in the object correct?  If not, how is it wrong?
2. Is the way I'm reading the lines of the file correct?  If not, how can I get it right?
3. Finally, is the way I'm printing the returned object correct?

This is really important to me.  If there is any way that I can improve the structure of my code, i.e. making a global variable for file handling or changing the structure of the object, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `openFiles` piece is correct.

The errors occur primarily `getItemDescription` method.

First as previously mentioned `my $self = @_;` should be `my ($self) = @_;`.

However, the crux of the question is solved in the following fashion:

Change `chomp(my $record = $self->{itemsFile});` to two lines:

`$file1 = $self->{itemsFile};`

`chomp(my $record = $file1);`

To clarify you must (in my experience and I tried all the solutions suggested) use a scalar value.

Finally, see the last two paragraphs in ikagami's answer.

Answer (score 4):

### Is the way I'm saving the file handle in the object correct?

Yes.

### Is the way I'm reading the lines of the file correct?

No. That just assigns the file handle. One reads a line from the file using the `readline` operator.

One would normally use the `<...>` syntax of the `readline` operator, but `<...>` is a shortcut for both `readline(...)` and `glob(qq<...>)`, and Perl thinks `<$self->{itemsFile}>` is short for `glob(qq<$self->{itemsFile}>)`. You have to use `readline` specifically

```
my $record = readline($self->{itemsFile});
chomp($record) if defined($record);
```

or do some extra work

```
my $fh = $self->{itemsFile};
my $record = <$fh>;
chomp($record) if defined($record);
```

(Note that I don't call `chomp` unconditionally since `readline`/`<>` can return undef.)

### Finally, is the way I'm printing the returned object correct?

I presume you mean returned string, as in the string returned by `getItemDescription`. The catch is, you never actually call the method. `->getItemDescription()` has no meaning in double quoted string literals, even after a variable. You need to move `$self->getItemDescription()` out of the double quotes.

You also fail to check if you've reached the end of the file.

Comment: It's not working.  The response I'm getting is 'TSJobsGenerator=HASH(0x2592d4)->getItemDescription(), Can't use string ("1") as HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at TSJobsGenerator.pm line 62.

Comment: That's because of the unrelated error in `my $self = @_;`. It should be `my ($self) = @_;`

Answer (score 2):

You are close.

To read a record (line) from a filehandle, you use the builtin `readline` function or the `<...>` operator AFTER you assign the filehandle to a "simple scalar" (see edit below).

```
chomp(my $record = readline( $self->{itemsFile} );

my $fh = $self->{itemsFile};
chomp(my $record = <$fh>);
```

There is also a bug in your `getItemDescription` method. You'll want to say

```
my ($self) = @_;
```

instead of

```
my $self = @_;
```

The latter call is a scalar assignment of an array, which resolves to the length of the array, not the first element of the array.

EDIT: `<$self->{itemsFile}>` and `<{$self->{itemsFile}}>` do not work, [as `perlop` explains](http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/pod/perlop.pod#I/O_Operators):

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be globbed, and either a list of filenames or the next filename in the list is returned, depending on context. This distinction is determined on syntactic grounds alone. That means `<$x>` is always a `readline()` from an indirect handle, but `<$hash{key}>` is always a `glob()`. That's because `$x` is a simple scalar variable, but `$hash{key}` is not--it's a hash element. Even `<$x >` (note the extra space) is treated as `glob("$x ")`, not `readline($x)`.

Comment: Cool.  So would you suggest a global variable $fileHandle that I use for files throughout this object?  Is that the best solution from an architecture perspective?

Comment: What? No, noone suggested global vars. That would be an awful idea.

Comment: Ikegami, if my understanding is correct mob is saying that storing filehandles in an object aren't going to be read correctly according to his edit or am I missing something?

Comment: Or something. He didn't say that either. Do you understand my answer better than his? We're both saying the same thing.

Comment: What doesn't work correctly is the combination of "complex expression" for the filehandle and the `<>` operator. You can pass your complex scalar to `readline`. Or you can copy the object member to a simple scalar and use the `<>` operator.